# Best practice to make partial search results appear (one by one as they come in from a secondary server)

Tags: python, ajax, django, cgi, daemon

I'd like to do the following:

- the queries on a django site (first server) are send to a second
  server (for performance and security reasons)
- the query is processed on the second server using sqlite
- the python search function has to keep a lot of data in memory. a simple cgi would always have to reread data from disk which would further slow down the search process. so i guess i need some daemon to run on the second server.
- the search process is slow and i'd like to send partial results back, and show them as they arrive.

this looks like a common task, but somehow i don't get it.

i tried Pyro first which exposes the search class (and then i needed a workaround to avoid sqlite threading issues). i managed to get the complete search results onto the first server, but only as a whole. i don't know how to "yield" the results one by one (as generators cannot be pickled), and i anyway wouldn't know how to write them one by one onto the search result page.

i may need some "push technology" says this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346075/1389074 talking about some different framework. but which?

i don't seem to search for the right terms. maybe someone can point me to some discussions or frameworks that address this task?

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python [tornado websockets](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/websocket.html).  This will allow you to establish 2 way connection from the client side to the server and return data as it comes.  Tornado is an async framework built in python.

Comment: very good hint, thank you!

i've read around tornado and i understand now that i actually should have separated the question, because i want all interaction to go via the http server:
 
 **client -1- http-server -2- database-server**
 
--- so i have two separate problems: keep the connection 2 alive and pass the obtained results one by one to the client via tornado on connection 1.